# Array of string using pandas_udf

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This function returns array of int:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

@F.pandas_udf('array<int>')
def pudf(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series([[x, y]])
```

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(5, 2), (6, 7)])
df = df.withColumn('out', pudf('_1', '_2'))

df.show()
# +---+---+------+
# | _1| _2|   out|
# +---+---+------+
# |  5|  2|[5, 2]|
# |  6|  7|[6, 7]|
# +---+---+------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- _2: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- out: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

**Question.** How to return array or string?

If I change `int` to `string` and df elements to string, it fails to return the expected array of strings.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

@F.pandas_udf('array<string>')
def pudf(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series([[x, y]])

df = spark.createDataFrame([('5', '2'), ('6', '7')])
df = df.withColumn('out', pudf('_1', '_2'))

df.show()
```

> ```
> PythonException: 
>   An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 913, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
>   File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 311, in pyarrow.lib.array
>   File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
>   File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 122, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
> pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'Series' object
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

@F.pandas_udf('array<string>')
def pudf(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series([[x[0],y[0]]])

df = spark.createDataFrame([('5', '2'), ('6', '7')])
df = df.withColumn('out', pudf('_1', '_2'))

df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()

# +---+---+------+
# |_1 |_2 |out   |
# +---+---+------+
# |5  |2  |[5, 2]|
# |6  |7  |[6, 7]|
# +---+---+------+

# root
#  |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- out: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```